# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka consumer with time based auto commit

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Spring Cloud Stream app using the Kafka binder. It appears to be committing offsets automatically based on `AckMode=BATCH` (had to find that in debug mode as it doesn't appear documented). This is causing significant overhead to the broker in commit frequency.

I would like to either switch to using the native Kafka auto commit, e.g.:

```
enable.auto.commit: true
auto.commit.interval.ms: 5000
```

Or switch to using TIME config with 5000 ms ackTime as documented here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#committing-offsets

Is this possible using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka? Can you provide a sample config? Native configs above appear to be ignored (in configuration block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AckMode` is ignored if `enable.auto.commit` is `true`. Bear in mind, however, that, unless you are using the 0.10.1.0 client or above, the broker will perform a rebalance if your consumer is slow since, to support this mode, we have to invoke your listener on the consumer thread. See [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread).

Since (the upcoming) version 1.3, the listener is always invoked on the consumer thread because the rebalance threat is eliminated (1.3 and above use the 0.11 client).

You can also use `AckMode.TIME`, `AckMode.COUNT` or `AckMode.COUNT_TIME` for even more flexibility over commit intervals. You might find the `COUNT_TIME` provides the best of both worlds.

Bear in mind, the risk of redelivery after a failure is increased with time-based (or high count-based) ack strategies.

Comment: This is on the 0.10.2.1 client. How do I set AckMode.COUNT_TIME on a Spring Cloud Dataflow app?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read the question fully. Container Ackmodes are not currently configurab le in the Kafka binder. They will be in 2.0. Use, e.g. ...consumer.configuration.enable.auto.offset to set arbitrary consumer kafka props.

Comment: Also had to upgrade spring-cloud-stream-kafka-binder 1.1.2 -> 1.2.1 to get the config picked up. 1.1.2 was hard coded with enable.auto.commit=false. Thanks!